# VBA: copying excel columns: best practice for storing cell references?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a big file with data, updated weekly, from which a VBA script copies a lot of columns of various lengths and starting points, and then pastes these columns one by one into another file.

My question is how to best store the cell references that the script needs to be able to copy the correct columns? Currently there is a bunch of arrays storing the starting row number, starting column number, sheet number etc which are all indexed the same, and a loop function which does the actual copy paste work.

This (exceptionally bad?) solution would obviously be an absolute nightmare if the source file would change slightly at some point. So how should one do it better?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Since your code is working, this question might be better suited for the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) forum.

Comment: It's hard to say, since we don't know what you mean by `lot of columns of various lengths and starting points`. Anyway, it seems like a logical problem, not a coding one. How do _you_ know the ranges you want to copy? If there is a common rationale behind the selections, you could store that rules somehow. If there isn't one (eg. ColumnA, rows 2 to 5; ColumnM, rows 105 to 522), it would be very difficult, and probably you would have to hard-code the rules. In short: first solve the problem, then write the code.

Comment: Sorry if the question was poor. The code itself is working perfectly. The source file is always the same which is why I know the ranges I want to copy. My only problem is that I have hardcoded all the starting points of each column that is supposed to be copied in a huge array in the VBA syntax window. And if the source file would change at some point it will be very difficult to adjust it since the array is almost unreadable...I guess the alternative is to store these cell references in an excel sheet instead for structure and feed the array from there but is that recommended practice?

Answer (score 0):

Excel is using enumerations for this purpose. Enums are the most efficient way to assign names to constants.

```
[Private] Enum WeeklyReport
    FirstRow = 3
    StartColumn = 1         ' Columns:
    Text
    Values
    Totals = 17
    Remarks
End Enum
```

The above declaration specifies the enum `WeeklyReport` with 5 values, one row and 4 columns. `Text` has the value of 2 because if the value is omitted the previous is incremented by 1. Therefore, `Remarks` = 18.

You can call up the values by their full name, like, `WeeklyReport.Remarks` or by their short name, like `Remarks`. That's why Excel gives unique names to its enumerations, like `xlUp`, which you might be using all the time without even knowing the enumeration's name. The names given above are possible but not very good.

Enumerations are a data type of their own which is interchangeable with Long. Declared before any code, at the top of a code sheet, they are available throughout that sheet if Private, otherwise throughout the project.